Possible to control single ceiling fan + light with separate control switches?
I have two rooms with the same type of ceiling fan: multi-speed with dimmable integrated light (Hampton Bay Sidewinder). In the first room, I can successfully control both the light and fan with a single Lutron Maestro MACL-LFQ combo switch. In the second room, I would like to control the fan with two separate switches, a Diva for the light, and a fan control (PD-FSQN) switch for the fan. It’s not working for me. Is this approach possible and I’m just wiring incorrectly? I currently have load wire going to each switch, ground to each, and neutral to the fan control. The Diva is wired to the light, the fan control to the fan. The LED lights up on the Diva switch, but won’t control the fan light. The LED on the fan control switch doesn’t light up, even though the load wire is connected to it properly
I’d greatly appreciate any help
Images here

Neutral is not used on switches(smart switches use neutral for their power).  A white hot might be, but that is for older houses.  Add pictures of the switch wires.

Thank you. Image link added
